# Link not working in react-router-dom when have same path but different params

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, routes, react-router-dom

The links work fine except if I'm in a UserProfile page. When I'm on UserProfile page and try to click on a link that links to another user profile page, the url will change but the new UserProfile will not render.

This is my `app.js`.

```js
<BrowserRouter>
  <div>
    <Header authenticated={this.state.authenticated} currentUserId={this.state.currentUserId}/>
    <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/homepage" render={(props) => {
                  return <HomePage authenticated={this.state.authenticated} {...props} />
                }} />
      <Route exact path="/login" render={(props) => {
                  return <Login setCurrentUser={this.setCurrentUser} setCurrentUserId = {this.setCurrentUserId} authenticated={this.state.authenticated} {...props} />
                }} />
      <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout}/>
      <Route exact path="/search" component={Search}/>
      <Route exact path="/forum" component={Forum}/>
      <Route path="/user/:id" component={UserProfile} currentUserId={this.state.currentUserId}/>
      <Route path="/wip/:wipId" component={WIP} currentUserId={this.state.currentUserId}/>
      <Route exact path="/submit_wip/:userId" render={(props) => {
                return <NewWIPForm authenticated={this.state.authenticated} currentUserId={this.state.currentUserId} {...props} />
              }} />
      <Route exact path="/edit_profile" render={(props) => {
                return <EditProfileForm authenticated={this.state.authenticated} currentUserId={this.state.currentUserId} {...props} />
              }} />
      <Route path="/edit_wip/:wipId" render={(props) => {
                return <EditWIPForm authenticated={this.state.authenticated} currentUserId={this.state.currentUserId} {...props} />
              }} />
      <Route exact path="/submit_thread" render={(props) => {
                return <NewThreadForm authenticated={this.state.authenticated} currentUserId={this.state.currentUserId} {...props} />
              }} />
      <Route path="/thread/:threadId" component={Thread} currentUserId={this.state.currentUserId}/>
    </Switch>
    {this.state.authenticated ? null :  (<Redirect to="/login" />)}
  </div>
</BrowserRouter>
```

And then on the UserProfile page I'll have a link to other UserProfiles like so:

```js
<Link to={"/user/" + review.reviewerId}>
  <Image className="reviewer-avatar" src={review.reviewerAvatar} responsive />
  <div className="reviewer-name">{review.reviewerName}</div>
</Link>
```

If you can find other things wrong with my code please feel free to point it out.

Comment: Do you have any errors in console?

Comment: @MatanBobi no console errors seemingly related to this. there was one about children can't have the same key when I clicked on the links but then I got rid of the key to see what would happen and nothing is happening.

Comment: Are you using your `currentUserId` inside the component? Because you pass it to the `Route` component and not to the `UserProfile` component.

Comment: try to do `console.log(this.props.match.params.id)` in render method of `UserProfile` to see if it doesn't print `id` when you click on a link.

Comment: When you use <Switch>, the code in componentWillMount() or componentDidMount() is not execute in this case, you can use componentWillReceiveProps() to manage your params in the url.